# How to execute Allure command using Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, allure

I want to generate test case wise reports in respective folder. So for example if I run login test case , it's allure html report should save in /reports/login.

I can do it easily by executing below command manually once my test execution completes. Command I use is :

```
allure generate allure-results -o E:\project\target\reports\loginReport --clean
```

But here difficulty is I have to execute command manually every time to generate report.

So I decided to execute this allure command from java , I tried following code :

```
 String cmd = "allure generate allure-results -o E:\\project\target\\reports\\loginReport --clean";
 Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
 process.waitFor();
```

I am calling above code as last test in my code. But getting error :

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "allure": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

so question is how can I execute above command from my java code. I am using Java, selenium, TestNG and maven.

**Note :** I have already set class path for allure package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code works perfectly fine for me. I have Java 1.8 installed on my mac machine.

```
String[] cmd = {"allure", "serve","/Users/kireeti/IdeaProjects/testautomationframeworkshaft/allure-results"};
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    Thread.sleep(90000);
```

Comment: Hi, Below command works for now but it deleted my whole project rather than just a targeted folder : `C:\allure-2.6.0\bin\allure.bat generate allure-results -o E:\project\target\reports\loginReport --clean`

Comment: Strange. try removing the '--clean' modifier and see if it is causing this behavior. Not sure if the allure clean will delete the project. Does it happen when you run the command by code (`exec(cmd)`) or does it happen manually too?

Comment: No it does not happen when I run it via cmd. Now I have changed command to C:\allure-2.6.0\bin\allure.bat generate `E:\project\allure-results\Login\LoginResult -o E:\project\allure-results\Login\LoginReport` But report comes blank. I am executing above command from @aftersuite method.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "allure" (in directory "D:\gitProjects\workProject"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified,.......... I am getting this error using above code above code